# Evaluate $\int \frac {x\sin\left(x\right) }{ \sqrt{3 + \sin^{2}\left(x\right)}}\; \operatorname dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate the indefinite integral

$$
\int \dfrac {x\sin\left(x\right) }{ \sqrt{3 + \sin^{2}\left(x\right)}}\; \operatorname dx
$$

> I think it's hard work to solve and I don't have any idea. So please give an idea to solve this problem, and I will think about it, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$3+\sin^2x=4-\cos^2x\;\implies \int\frac{\sin x\,dx}{\sqrt{4-\cos^2x}}=$$

$$=\int\frac{\frac{\sin x}2\,dx}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{\cos x}2\right)^2}}$$

And now use:

**Integration by parts:**

$$u=x\;,\;\;v'=\frac{\sin}{\sqrt{3+\sin^2x}}$$

**Almost immediate integrals:**

$$\int\frac{f'(x)dx}{\sqrt{1-f^2(x)}}=\arcsin f(x)+C$$

Comment: Unless you write the full answer, I don't see how is the $x$-factor involved in your answer.

Comment: @FelixMarin 
$$u=x\;\;,\;\;u'=1\\v'=-\frac{-\sin x}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2}}=-\frac{-\frac{\sin x}2}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{\cos x}2\right)^2}}\;\;,\;\;v=\arcsin\frac{\cos x}2$$